# Authentication to API through Symfony Client

Tags: rest, symfony, authentication

I'm currently working on some sort of atypic architecture.

My Symfony 2 app is gonna be at the same time deploying a RESTful API and querying it through GuzzleHttp Client. My API calls are batched, unserialization is automated and performances improvement is really interesting.

But… what about user authentication between during API calls processes as my API client is on server-side (and is in fact the same SF2 app) ?

**User X** --> (log in) --> **Symfony "Client"** --> (*HTTP Calls*) --> **API**

I know that solution may be found using JWT, but I'm not working on a SPA. Some parts of my front are going to be updated with JS (and i'm gonna use JWT for them), but most of it will be built by the "SF Client".

The only idea i've got is to send credentials received by the "Client" to the API to be authenticated and then store the JWT returned in database to be able to send it for every next call. It kinda feels to be the dirty way… ?

Thx !